# System.currentTimeMillis() keeps resetting

Tags: java, minecraft

I'm trying to make a cooldown utility in my spigot plugin:

```
package net.gettrillium.trillium.api.cooldown;

import com.google.common.collect.HashBasedTable;
import com.google.common.collect.Table;
import net.gettrillium.trillium.Utils;
import org.bukkit.Bukkit;
import org.bukkit.entity.Player;

import java.util.UUID;

public class Cooldown {

private static Table<UUID, CooldownType, Long> cooldown = HashBasedTable.create();

public static void setCooldown(Player p, CooldownType type) {
    cooldown.put(p.getUniqueId(), type, System.currentTimeMillis());
}

public static boolean hasCooldown(Player p, CooldownType type) {
    if (cooldown.contains(p.getUniqueId(), type)) {
        Bukkit.broadcastMessage("GET: " + cooldown.get(p.getUniqueId(), type));
        Bukkit.broadcastMessage("CURRENT MILLIS: " + System.currentTimeMillis());
        Bukkit.broadcastMessage("SUBTRACTED: " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - cooldown.get(p.getUniqueId(), type)));
        Bukkit.broadcastMessage("IN SECONDS: " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - cooldown.get(p.getUniqueId(), type)) / 1000.0);
        Bukkit.broadcastMessage("> WITH: " + (type.getTimeInTicks() / 20));
        Bukkit.broadcastMessage("HAS COOLDOWN: " + (((System.currentTimeMillis() - cooldown.get(p.getUniqueId(), type)) / 1000.0) > (type.getTimeInTicks() / 20)));
        if (((System.currentTimeMillis() - cooldown.get(p.getUniqueId(), type)) / 1000.0) > (type.getTimeInTicks() / 20)) {
            return true;
        } else {
            cooldown.remove(p.getUniqueId(), type);
            return false;
        }
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

public static String getTime(Player p, CooldownType type) {
    if (hasCooldown(p, type)) {
        return Utils.timeToString((int) ((System.currentTimeMillis() - cooldown.get(p.getUniqueId(), type)) / 1000.0));
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
}
```

The `bukkit.broadcastMessage()` method simply sends the message to the console and in game as debugging.

My problem is that every time I check the `cooldown` table, `cooldown.contains(p.getUniqueId(), type)` is always a new `System.currentTimeMillis()`. It's not saving the one registered in setCooldown.

This `Cooldown` class is used here in the teleport module, all you need to note are the if statements that are related to the `cooldown`, everything else is just [teleport](https://github.com/TeamTrillium/Trillium/blob/master/src/main/java/net/gettrillium/trillium/modules/TeleportModule.java#L73) related code.

The debug output:

```
GET: 1433433920944
CURRENT MILLIS: 1433433928830
SUBTRACTED: 7888
IN SECONDS: 7.889
WITH: 20
HAS COOLDOWN: false
```

Can anyone explain why?

Comment: There must be something wrong with your logic in `hasCooldown()`: you return `false` and delete the existing entry if the method is called **too soon** after the cooldown was set. Did you mean to do that if it's called **too long** after it was set? Maybe you have that `if` statement backwards?

Comment: Where is setCooldown called?

Comment: Can you include the debugging output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a simple logic bug in `hasCooldown()`. You can see from your debug output, that even though the time in seconds is less than the cooldown length, it's returning `false` for having a cooldown.

You can see why easier by using temporary variables in your calculations. When you find an entry in your map, you're doing the equivalent of this:

```
long startMillis = cooldown.get(p.getUniqueId(), type);
double elapsedSecs = (System.currentTimeMillis() - startMillis) / 1000.0;
long cooldownSecs = type.getTimeInTicks() / 20;
boolean hasCooldown = elapsedSecs > cooldownSecs  // wrong!
```

That's backwards: if `elapsedSecs > cooldownSecs`, then the cooldown has timed out. The cooldown is still valid if `cooldownSecs < elapsedSecs`.

So, when `elapsedSecs < cooldownSecs`, `hasCooldown()` erroneously thinks the cooldown has timed out, so it deletes it and returns `false`. I'm sure some other part of your code, finding no cooldown, inserts a new one, which is why you're seeing a new one.